# ember.js: notify entry creation in nested route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a problem: I add an object, and i would like it to be appended 'live' to my list of objects, in a context of nested routes. Being in Ember.js context, i don't want to notify this change, it should auto-update.

Is it possible?

given this router:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @resource "raw_materials", ->
    @route 'new'
```

and these templates:

raw_materials.hbl

```
{{#linkTo raw_materials.new}}CREATE{{/linkTo}}
<ul>
  {{#each controller}}
  <li>
    {{name}} - {{quantity}}
  </li>
{{outlet}}
```

raw_materials/new.hbl

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="name"}}
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="quantity"}}
<a {{action 'create' this}}>V</a>
```

controller:

```
App.RawMaterialsNewController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  create: (params)->
    App.RawMaterial.createRecord({
      name: params.name,
      quantity: params.quantity
    })
    @get("store").commit()
```

so that the result is this:
[image: result]

UPDATE:
my current route is:

```
App.RawMaterialsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.RawMaterial.find({})
```

if i change it in

```
App.RawMaterialsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.RawMaterial.find()
```

the problem is resolved.

The reason why i used `.find({})` is that it gives me the isLoaded event, while with `.find()` the array isLoaded is always true, also when it's not loaded

What can I do?

Thank you

Comment: i'm not quite sure since the documentation is somewhat lacking in that regard, but maybe using the controller's `filteredContent` could help. otherwise, working with a computed property instead of the content is also a possibility, i think.

Comment: i reasoned about it: i think it's better to leave the `.find()`, and calculate in another way the content loading. In that case everything will work as expected. However i don't like this feature of ember

Comment: `find({})` will use `findQuery` (which calls `AdapterPopulatedRecordArray::load` that triggers once `isLoaded` whereas `find()` will use `findAll`. But also it won't take advantage of the cache.